# DataTable Select Method "not intended to be used"?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use a LINQ expression to convert each row in a DataTable into an entry in a List object.

My code:

```
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

var intList = new List<int>(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => int.Parse(row["IntColumn"].ToString())));
```

This actually works when I run the code, but I'm concerned because when I hover over my use of .Select() I see this (**Note: I am using ReSharper 8.2.2000.5102**):

[image: Resharper tooltip for .Select()]

The part that concerns me is this, "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

My question is: How should I be doing this if I'm not supposed to be using the EnumerableRowCollection implementation of .Select()?

Comment: Possibly insert a `.ToList()` in between the enumerable and the select.

Comment: @RonBeyer This works for sure, but it still seems odd that I would have to do this.

Comment: It seems that its not the `.Select` that is considered an API, its `EnumerableRowCollection` itself. You could also convert this to a LINQ query, something like `var intList = (from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable() select int.Parse(r["IntColumn"].ToString())).ToList()` which should eliminate the warning as well.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, that's not a warning. That message appears if you hover your mouse pointer on the Select() method. It's part of the XML documentation of the method.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen Its not a compiler warning, its a "documented warning" or an "advisory", or whatever you want to call it, doesn't matter really as its "warning" you that you probably shouldn't be using that API.

Comment: @Rob Beyer, when I said that's not a warning, I mean it was not a compiler warning. The message is indeed a warning message written in the XML documentation.

Comment: @RonBeyer if you would like to put your first and maybe second comment into the form of an answer I would readily accept it as the correct answer for my question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerable row collection is marked as an "Internal API Class" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx) so you get that "warning" because its included in the documentation.

A number of the selects are also marked as "Internal API", specifically the one that you are using. Either you have to convert it to a List with the `.ToList()` before the select, or you can write a LINQ query like:

```
var intList = (from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable() 
               select int.Parse(r["IntColumn"].ToString())).ToList()
```

You could also use one of the `Select` statements that is not marked as an API, specifically:

```
Select<TRow, TResult>(Func<TRow, TResult>)
Select<TRow, TResult>(Func<TRow, Int32, TResult)
```

Or one of the similarly named overloads. See the linked documentation for details. Its difficult to force it from one overload to the other because many of the overloads contain the same signature, so this may be the problem.